# C#-Code in 2 Projects for a logger and a service, ERROR

Tags: c#

I am trying to get my EasyLogger C# Project to work, but I can't debug this code because it is a Class Library. I use this logger in a Windows Console Application which is installed with squirrel as a Windows Service, so I can't see whats inside the variables....

What do I wrong?

This is in a Windows Console Application:

```
        public void Start()
        {
            //Define EasyLogger
            EasyLogger.Logger.Loggerpath = @"C:\Development\ServerSF";
            EasyLogger.Logger.Logname = "Testlog";

            Thread.Sleep(1000);


            //Start EasyLogger
            bool test = EasyLogger.Logger.Log;
            EasyLogger.Logger.StartLog();

            if (test == true)
            {
                //Start service
                _timer.Start();
                ExThred(configManager.ServerName);
            }
            else
            {
                //ERROR log isnt started
            }
        }
```

This is my EasyLogger Project:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace EasyLogger
{
    public static class Logger
    {
        #region GET SET      
        private static string loggerpath;
        private static string logname;
        private static string message;
        private static bool log;
        public static string Loggerpath
        {
            get => loggerpath;
            set => loggerpath = value;
        }
        public static string Logname
        {
            get => logname;
            set => logname = value;
        }
        public static string Message
        {
            get => message;
            set => message = value;
        }
        public static bool Log
        {
            get => log;
            set => log = value;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Logger
        private static readonly string loggingpath = loggerpath + @"\logs\"+ logname + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss") + ".txt";

        public static void StartLog()
        {
            if(loggerpath == null)
            {
                Message = "Program path is empty!";
                log = false;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(loggingpath))
                    {
                        byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Logger v0.1 Started...");
                        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
                    }
                    log = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Message = "Can't create logfile!";
                    log = false;
                }  
            }
        }

        public static void WriteLog(string msg)
        {
            if (Logname != null)
            {
                if (log == true)
                {
                    string[] lines = new string[] { DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - " + msg };
                    File.AppendAllLines(loggingpath, lines);
                }
                else
                {
                    try { Message = "Logger isn't started yet!"; }
                    catch { Message = "Logger Error!"; }
                }
            }
            else { Message = "Please define first a Logname!"; }
        }

        public static void StopLog()
        {
            log = false;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Do it like the big ones: Include "internal" logging in the logging lib. (Or use one of the big ones in the first place.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not the logger. Your problem is **how to debug a Windows Service.**

With Visual Studio, you can do it this way:

1. Compile your Windows service with Debug informaton.
2. Install the Service and run it.
3. Start Visual Studio.
4. Select "Debug" --> "Attach Process"
5. Click "Show processes from all users"
6. Search for your service and click "Attach".
7. Select "Common Language Runtime"